# Programs started by windows script close immediately

Tags: python, windows-8

Here is my bat file which tries to run some python script:

```
cd Users\Me\Projects
start python Chord.py -i ini
for /l %%a in (8001,1,8101) do (
    ping /n 5 127.0>nul
    start python Chord.py -p %%a %%a
)
echo. & pause
```

It runs well on a Win7 machine, while on my Win8, each program closes immediately after the launch, I tried to run as administrator and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call those by cmd.exe instead:

```
cd Users\Me\Projects
start python Chord.py -i ini
for /l %%a in (8001,1,8101) do (
    ping /n 5 127.0>nul
    start cmd.exe /c python Chord.py -p %%a %%a
)
echo. & pause
```